# How to call HttpPost method from other namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am working on a project with AWS services (SQS and DynamoDB). It is my first project using them so it is a little test project to see how everything works.
I almost have what I want to achieve which is posting the message gained from the SQS queue and putting it inside a dynamoDB table.

I can put stuff inside a dynamoDB table and I can fetch from the SQS queue, but now I am stuck on simply calling the method from the controller and passing the message body.

**Controller class:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DataModel;
using TimelineService.Model;

namespace TimelineService.Controller
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TimelineController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IDynamoDBContext _context;

        public TimelineController(IDynamoDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreatePost(Post postRequest)
        {
            var post = await _context.LoadAsync<Post>(postRequest.Id);
            if (post != null) return BadRequest($"Post with Id {postRequest.Id} Already Exists");
            await _context.SaveAsync(postRequest);
            return Ok(postRequest);
        }

    }
}
```

**The SQS Processor class**

```
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.SQS;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.SQS.Model;

namespace TimelineService.SQSProcessor
{
    public class TimelineProcessor : BackgroundService
    {
        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting background processor");
            var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("MYCREDENTIALS", "MYCREDENTIALS");
            var client = new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);

            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Getting messages from the queue {DateTime.Now}");
                var request = new ReceiveMessageRequest()
                {
                    QueueUrl = "https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/075206908135/PostTimelineQueue",
                    WaitTimeSeconds = 15,
                    VisibilityTimeout = 20//for long polling

                };
                var response = await client.ReceiveMessageAsync(request);
                foreach (var message in response.Messages)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
                    if (message.Body.Contains("Exception")) continue; //send to dead letter queue if message contains exception
                    //call createmethod and put message body inside 

                    await client.DeleteMessageAsync("MySQS", message.ReceiptHandle);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the TimelineProcessor class I have commented the following line

```
 //call createmethod and put message body inside
```

where I want the posting into the dynamoDB to happen.
I simply need to call the CreatePost method from the controller class and pass the message body with it, but I can seem to get it to work.

Since working with c# and ASP.net was a long time ago I just forgot how I should do it and can't seem to google it.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've got the dependencies mixed up or you misunderstand what a controller is - if you do not have an API and it is simply a background service (assumed from you using `BackgroundService`) then you do not need the controller. Just new up the context in your service and use it there. Or you can new up the controller (not recommended). Or you can call the endpoint (really really not recommended).

Comment: If you *are* using the controller, abstract the code within `CreatePost` into a `DynamoDBService` and then inject the service into the controller while also injecting/newing it up in your background service. The controller shouldn't really have much logic within it other than routing requests and responses.